# Spring/Hibernate and relational mapping

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC and Hibernate (and also databases in general), so would like some help.

Currently I have 2 tables in my database - Booking and Restaurant. Booking has a foreign key `R_id` that points to the primary key of Restaurant. Right now I'm trying to implement a drop-down menu which displays all the restaurants in the database and when the user chooses a restaurant, the value is set in that Booking database. I hope you understand what I mean.

My Booking class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking")
public class Booking {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="R_id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @Column(name="date")
    @Type(type="date")
    private Date date;

    @Column(name="start")
    @Type(type="time")
    private Date start;

    @Column(name="duration")
    private float duration;

    @Column(name="amount_of_people")
    private int amountOfPeople;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="contact_preference")
    private String contactPreference;

    @Column(name="comments")
    private String comments;

    @Column(name="current_datetime")
    @Type(type="timestamp")
    private Date currentDatetime;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
        return restaurant;
    }

    public void setRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(Date start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public float getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(float duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public int getAmountOfPeople() {
        return amountOfPeople;
    }

    public void setAmountOfPeople(int amountOfPeople) {
        this.amountOfPeople = amountOfPeople;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContactPreference() {
        return contactPreference;
    }

    public void setContactPreference(String contactPreference) {
        this.contactPreference = contactPreference;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public Date getCurrentDatetime() {
        return currentDatetime;
    }

    public void setCurrentDatetime(Date currentDatetime) {
        this.currentDatetime = currentDatetime;
    }

}
```

Restaurant class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="restaurant_name")
    private String restaurantName;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRestaurantName() {
        return restaurantName;
    }

    public void setRestaurantName(String restaurantName) {
        this.restaurantName = restaurantName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return restaurantName;
    }

}
```

Relevant methods in MainController:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "booking/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createBooking(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("booking", new Booking());
        initModelList(model);
        return "newBooking";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "booking/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createBookingAction(Booking booking) {
        bookingService.addBooking(booking);
        return "redirect:/bookings";
    }

     .....

    private void initModelList(Model model) {
    List<Restaurant> restaurantList = restaurantService.getRestaurants();
        model.addAttribute("restaurants", restaurantList);

    }
```

And here is my jsp file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<jsp:include page="../fragments/head.jsp"/>
<body>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/menu.jsp"/>
<div id="body">
    <h2>Create new booking</h2>

    <form:form method="POST" commandName="booking" class="bookingForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Restaurant:</td>
                <td><form:select path="restaurant">
                    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                    <form:options items="${restaurants}" />
                </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
    <div>
        <a href="/bookings">Back to List</a>
    </div>
</div>
<jsp:include page="../fragments/footer.jsp"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Right now the drop-down menu displays the restaurants but when I click submit it gives me this error: `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

I think it's because there is something wrong with the mapping between Booking and Restaurant, but I don't know what it is. Sorry for the long post, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller `booking/create POST` is expecting a valid `Booking` object in the request you are sending from your JSP form.

You can try changing

```
<form:select path="restaurant">
```

to

```
<form:select path="restaurant.restaurantName">
```

Since the form itself will add the contents to a booking object so this field will effectively map to `booking.restaurant.restaurantName`, which makes it a valid Booking object.

Also note that your controller at this point will be getting a booking object with just one field having data. you need to fetch the rest of the data of related objects from db (like ids), before saving the data.

Comment: instead of `restaurentName`, it could be `id`, i'm bit confused.. try both

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use dedicated Forms, it's a way good practice.

In your case it would be a dedicated user class named `BookingAddForm` with raw datatypes like `Integer` and `String` including collections that contain the only info you need for the operation, in your case the restaurant names list. So, the complex object list binding simple wouldn't be needed and would everything work fine.

After, you can easily handle it on the service layer. Create there your Hibernate entities from the data you've loaded and handle it however you need. The same story for data retrieving.

---

At the code you've specified you've missed `@ModelAttribute` annotation to associate the form with your controller. It should be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "booking/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createBookingAction(@ModelAttribute @Valid BookingAddForm bookingAddForm, BindingResult br) {

    // validation required!
    bookingService.addBooking(bookingAddForm);

    return "redirect:/bookings";
}
```

... also note, you don't perform any validation. You have to, otherwise your app ain't  safe.

[@Valid annotation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)